# How to wrap to content Android preference summary value?

Tags: android, preferences, summary

How to increase (wrap to content) the size of the preference summary value?

It is currently showing maximum of 105 characters.

Comment: In fact, the interesting thing is that on some devices (top models) there are more characters shown, on some (lower resolution middle tier model)- less (by about 50 chars). Also looking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding to my EditTextPreferences:

```
android:layout="@layout/edit_text_preference_layout"
```

and copying the standard Android layout XML to my own layout file (edit_text_preference_layout.xml) with some alterations (i.e. removing the maxlines attribute and changing the font size and margins to match other preferencies exactly (for some reason, the preferences.xml in sdk (both 7 and 19) had values making the affected pref looking a bit different from what I had on my screen for standard prefs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

So, if you have other preferences  - their layouts should be altered too, so everything looks consistent on the prefs screen.